# Export all column values except the last column in repeater to excel to using VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to export all columns to excel except the last column which is and edit / delete column.

I have the following code which exports all columns in the repeater.

any help with formatting my excel would be great.

```
Protected Sub Excel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & Format(Now(), "ddMMMyyyy-hh.mm.ss") & ".xls")
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
    Dim htm As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    '--Load data from SQL DB
    Loaddata()

    Repeater1.RenderControl(htm)
    Response.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered using CSV format instead of HTML to get the data into Excel? There are even free Nuget packages which will output .xlsx format data for you.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Yes I am open to using CSV formats

Comment: Do any of the fields contain double-quotes or commas? If not, you can just concatenate them with commas with a StringBuilder. (Note that the old trick of naming a download file with an extension of .xls does not necessarily work with newer versions of Excel.)

Comment: It is possible that one field may occasionally contain quotes/commas.

Comment: In that case, and I haven't tried it myself, but [CsvExport](https://github.com/jitbit/CsvExport) looks like it might work well for you, assuming the licence is acceptable. (Don't worry that it says C#, it will work with VB.NET too.) There are other csv export packages available too, just search for "nuget csv export".